# create graph in nvd3.js with proper values

Tags: javascript, graph, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js first time in my php code.
I want to show a graph count against date for particular user. I want to show the date horizontally and count vertically. But I did not understand how to do that. 
My json data is like:`["key":"0","values":[["1374517800000","2"]]},"182398":{"key":"182398","values":[["1375295400000","2"],["1374517800000","2"],["1374604200000","12"],["1374431400000","1"],["1375122600000","4"],["1375209000000","19"]]},"185271":{"key":"185271","values":[["1374604200000","2"],["1374517800000","1"]]]` and

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {  
    chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]})
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]})
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
    .clipVoronoi(false);

    chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    });

    chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

    d3.select('#cumulative_line_chart svg')
    .datum(stageArr)
    //.transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

    //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    //nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    return chart;
    });
```

Now in this case my first problem is date is not showing properly(I converted the date to strtotime() and then concat 000 with the date e.g `1375295400000 =strtotime("23-07-2013")."000"` and this conversion is happening in php).
Second issue is in y axis I want to show the integer like 2,12,4,19(as per above json data) etc.
So please guide me how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Sorry to say that it is not d3.js but it is nvd3.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this ? And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/gxb6r/) is a working version of the cde

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart().margin({
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 45
    }).showLegend(true).tooltipContent(function (key, y, e, graph) {
        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' + '<p>' + e + '% at ' + y + '</p>'
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    });

    d3.select('#lineChart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});

data = [{
    "values": [{
        "x": 1025409600000 ,
            "y": 2
    }, {
        "x": 1028088000000 ,
            "y": 4
    }, {
        "x": 1030766400000 ,
            "y": 1
    }, {
        "x": 1033358400000 ,
            "y": 3
    }, {
        "x": 1036040400000  ,
            "y": 0
    }, {
        "x": 1038632400000  ,
            "y": 3
    }],
        "key": "Sine Wave",
}]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please tell me the date format. How I have to represent it lets say it is 06-12-2012?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the scale of the axis : it's not computed from you data, but you can use helper function for d3, like d3.max ...

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                 .range([0, w]);
```

c.f. http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales

Then, you can add the scale definition to the axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(xScale)
              .orient("bottom");
```

c.f. http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes

Comment: nvd3.js and d3.js are same? If not please help regarding nvd3.js. Sorry to change it.

Comment: my mystake : i didn't know about nvd3.js, i just use and like d3.js.

Comment: @Mausumi NVD3 is a set re-usable charts for built on top of d3.js.