# Passing data for nvd3 chart from Flask as an argument

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask, nvd3.js

I am using Flask with nvd3 to display charts. My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055791/create-graph-in-nvd3-js-with-proper-values) (check out the answer), except that now I want the json `data` variable to be initialized by passing an argument from Flask instead of hard-coding it in the javascript.

Doing `data = {{data}}` and rendering the template by

`return render_template("display_plot.html", data=data)`
where I generate the data using python e.g.

`data = {"values": [{"y": 17830, "x": 1382313600000.0}, {"y": 17977, "x": 1382400000000.0}, {"y": 17633, "x": 1382486400000.0}, {"y": 17633, "x": 1382572800000.0}, {"y": 17403, "x": 1382659200000.0}, {"y": 17403, "x": 1382745600000.0}, {"y": 17142, "x": 1382832000000.0}], "key": "active_pages", "yAxis": "1"}]` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, you should call data as:

```
{{ data|tojson|safe }}
```

Otherwise, you will not get the correct results since the data is technically not converted to json and also the characters might be escaped by jinja.